# How to put echo response (text) in alert box via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, response, echo

i'm new to php and ajax and i`m trying to send a php form data via ajax (without the reflesh) and display the echo msg of the php on an alert box via ajax sucess, but it didnt work.
The code goes like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "env.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

and the php echo responses (send and error):

```
 $erros = "";

 if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
     $erros .= "O nome deve ser preenchido.";
 }

 if(empty($_POST['email']) ){
      $erros .= "O E-mail deve ser preenchido.";
 }else{
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      eregi("([\._0-9A-Za-z-]+)@([0-9A-Za-z-]+)(\.[0-9A-Za-z\.]+)",$email,$match);
    if(!isset($match)){
       $erros .= "O e-mail informado é inválido.";
    }
}

if(empty($_POST['mensagem'])){
    $erros .= "A mensagem deve ser preenchida.";
}
if( empty($erros) ){

all the code to get form data and send

 $send = $phpmail->Send();

    if($send){
        echo "A Mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.";
    }else{
        echo "Não foi possível enviar a mensagem. Erro: " .$phpmail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    }else{
        echo $erros;
    }
```

I want to put the echo message of env.php on the alert, but i really dont know how to do this, i tryied putting data, but it shows the entire document (with html on text form).
Can anyone help me please?

ps: the form is on a .html and the php on a .php

**EDIT:**

I tryied to add `$json = json_encode($erros);` but it wont work, how can i read this on the sucess ajax function? (on a alert box)

---

I tryied to add  $json = json_encode($erros); but it wont work, how can i read this on the sucess ajax function? (on a alert box)

Comment: try echo json_encode($errors);

Comment: Please confirm: is that the full code of env.php, or is the form there too?

Comment: every where you echo try to endode it with json_encode($var)

Comment: are you getting `all the code to get form data and send` in your error alert ?

Comment: The form is inside a div, what i get on submit click (alert: data) is all the html code from the site (index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this my friend  :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "env.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    var data_output = data;
                    alert(data_output);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`env.php` needs to respond to the AJAX call with only the data you want it to, not an entire page. All you have to do is modify `env.php` to not have all the HTML stuff you don't need.

Comment: The echo`s going this way:
    $send = $phpmail->Send();
 
    if($send){
        echo "A Mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.";
    }else{
        echo "Não foi possível enviar a mensagem. Erro: " .$phpmail->ErrorInfo;
    }
 
    }else{
whats wront?
        echo $erros;
    }

 ?>